# pandas to_csv() method saving string columns with leading space

Tags: pandas, anaconda, space

Is any one saw recently issue with Pandas pd.to_csv() method with leading space in column names and columns contain strings. This is making merge of 2 data frames messy. Issue appeared recently
After applying str.strip() issue resolved locally but making coding messy because of care for leading spaces.
Verified Pandas 0.19
Observed in Anaconda IDE
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list('xxx'), B=list('yyy')))

df
```

[image]

```
print(df.to_csv())

,A,B
0,x,y
1,x,y
2,x,y
```

---

I'm not seeing this behavior.

---

If this is being read from another csv you can use the parameter `skipinitialspace=True` to import without leading spaces.

I'm assuming leading spaces are in your dataframe and you can use this to address leading and trailing white space

```
for c, col in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).iteritems():
    df[c] = col.str.strip()
```

Comment: Thank you, is it 0.19 version?

Comment: thank you. Can you please try to open csv in Excel and verify?

Comment: @Felix confirmed!  No leading spaces in file or in Excel